# How to access first element of table in Lua?

Tags: lua

I want to access the nth element of a table I created like this:

```
t = { 0.0 , 0.0 }
```

How can I do this in Lua?

I understand I could use ipairs, but I would like a single-line solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The index is 1-based:

```
t[n]
```

The first element is:

```
t[1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saves me tons of time debugging my lua code...